# How can I extract bytes type JSON data from an API connection, and convert selected columns to a python data frame

Tags: python, json, api

**The following is my code with an API connection**:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("instagram47.p.rapidapi.com")

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "instagram47.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "fbac45a2a1mshd1552a6a4b5c40dp11f0fejsn87c5e6ebf342"
    }


conn.request("GET", "/user_following?userid=38500199922", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8")) ##This is byte data. 
d_string=json.dumps(d) #converting to strings using json.dumps
print(d_string)
```

**Result**:

```
{"body": {"page_size": 200, "next_max_id": "50", "status": "ok", "big_list": true, "users": [{"is_private": true, "pk": 10119571306, "full_name": "geraline lol \ud83e\uddd1\ud83c\udffd\u200d\ud83c\udfa4", "profile_pic_id": "2714545912561066205_10119571306", "username": "g3raline__", "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "is_favorite": false, "latest_reel_media": 0, "follow_friction_type": 0, "has_highlight_reels": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-mxp2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/260402731_244731964418125_2728204070967694144_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=yFi0ME-BwLoAX9VB2ws&edm=ALB854YBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT_hG7G8rRZ8kXgBjvTUXDmsKY0MdTkf-XxJXMZsmbLRWA&oe=61EE3BA7&_nc_sid=04cb80", "is_verified": false}, {"is_private": true, "pk": 29469548019, "full_name": "", "profile_pic_id": "2742223021579729541_29469548019", "username": "melannyski", "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "is_favorite": false, "latest_reel_media": 0, "follow_friction_type": 0, "has_highlight_reels": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-mxp2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/271273719_272733284842985_2676050159817911915_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=YYVyklHjfsgAX_eQwZc&edm=ALB854YBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT_TMiNQTrq3xuFWg4WIdxyv_MRfdxSwjsnKUplA1FWu5w&oe=61ED7336&_nc_sid=04cb80", "is_verified": false}, {"is_private": false, "pk": 53892051, "full_name": "Courtney Dickson", "profile_pic_id": "2733057419432607865_53892051", "username": "dirty_dickson1", "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "is_favorite": false, "latest_reel_media": 0, "follow_friction_type": 0, "has_highlight_reels": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-mxp2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/269483477_210224671299081_9007717381559573256_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=j-SUMBR2fWYAX-TR5Bz&edm=ALB854YBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8gtIqlMNabJb0c-vQkDcSVyyl9o0nErEdhaRzOp5jmig&oe=61EDB143&_nc_sid=04cb80", "is_verified": false}]}, "status": "Success", "statusCode": 404}
```

**Desired Result**: 
I want a list of all the username and full_name from users like this list in a python dataframe:

| username | full_name |
| --- | --- |
| dirty_dickson1 | Courtney Dickson |
| Some Username | Some Full Name |

Comment: First, in your code you have `json.dumps(d)` but no where in your code is there `d`. Also `res.read()` returns bytes and `data.decode("utf-8")` converts `bytes` to `str`. So there is no reason to use `json.dumps` to dump a `str` to a `str`. You need to convert the `str` to a `dict` using `json.loads` and then access what you need via `dict[]`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @TeddyBearSuicide. So after doing that as you advised, following: `d=json.loads(data)` and `d['body'][users]` I got the following which is nice: [{'is_private': True,
  'pk': 10119571306,
  'full_name': 'geraline lol \u200d',
  'profile_pic_id': '2714545912561066205_10119571306',
  'username': 'g3raline__',
  'has_anonymous_profile_picture': False,.                                                                      
But, how can I get further and pick out username from users? Thanks

Comment: @MYousefi has the code that would work for you. Though they didn't explain how it works. Basically `d['body']['users']` returns you a `list` of `dict`. You need to iterate over that list and grab what you need from the `dict` items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make pandas DataFrame object by either passing a list of dictionaries (treated as rows) or a single dictionary where the values are lists (treated as columns).

Here we read the json data and then create the data frame by extracting the values from the list and place them into separate dictionaries (rows of the data frame)

```
data = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
df = pd.DataFrame([{"username": u["username"], "full_name": u["full_name"]} for u in data["body"]["users"]])
```

Comment: Please avoid just posting code. Try to explain what your code does because a new programming might not fully understand what it is doing or how it works.

Comment: @MYousefi: Your line generated the data frame I needed. Thank you!